# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when trying to run my program (: No bean named 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean' is defined)  Yet the bean has been defined in the Beans2.xml file. The classes are listed below. Thanks.

PieceHibernateDAO.java

```
package sample.spring.chapter01;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
//import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionCallback;
//import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionTemplate;



@Repository(value="PieceHibernateDAO")
public class PieceHibernateDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public int createPieceHibernate(final Piece piece) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(piece);
        return piece.getpieceid();
    }

    //public Piece getPiece


    public void fill(Resource resource) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        InputStream is=resource.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));              


        CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader().parse(br);

        for (CSVRecord record:parser) {
            String ref=record.get("référence ascensoriste").trim();
            String asc=record.get("ascensoriste").trim();
            //String desc=record.get("Description article").trim();                
            String prix=record.get("Pv");
            String category=record.get("Familie").trim();
            //System.out.println(category);
            Piece lift_comp=new Piece();




            lift_comp.setasc(asc);
           //lift_comp.setdesc(desc);
            lift_comp.setref(ref);
            lift_comp.setprice(prix);
            lift_comp.settype(category);
            lift_comp.setinfo();
            //listp.add(lift_comp);
            int cpid=lift_comp.getcompanyid(asc);
            lift_comp.setcompanyid(cpid);

            //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(lift_comp);
            createPieceHibernate(lift_comp);
        }


    }



}
```

Beans2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="sample.spring" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liftcomp_db" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="8K887h))00" />
    </bean>


 <bean id="PieceHibernateDAO" 
 class="sample.spring.chapter01.PieceHibernateDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"/>
    </bean>



  <bean id="PieceDAO" class="sample.spring.chapter01.PieceDAO">
        <property name="listp" ref="Piece"></property>              
   </bean>
   <bean id = "Company" class = "sample.spring.chapter01.Company"/>
   <bean id = "Family" class = "sample.spring.chapter01.Family"/>
   <bean id = "Piece" class = "sample.spring.chapter01.Piece"/>   
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a bean with id `sessionFeactory`. this must be the value in the ref Attribute:

```
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

because this is the id of the bean.

Comment: I get the message "Attribute ref is not allowed to appear in element bean